# Matplotlib canvas doesn't stop updating even after event_source.stop() has been called

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, qthread

I'm working on a GUI using PyQT, in which there is a matplotlib figure needs to be updated real-time on a button press. Data is from sounddevice.InputStream and using callback function to get data. Currently working with QThread and Worker to do the figure update.

when I try to press the `self.start_test_button` the plot updates real time correctly, but when I press the `self.stop_test_button` although it correctly stops updating, but it flashes/stutters like something doesn't stop correctly
something like this
https://imgur.com/a/kkutBYW

`Worker()` class mainly gets the signal and start a timer where it will emit to a signal calling the `MainWindow.update_plot()` method

```
class Worker(QObject):
    timer_out = pyqtSignal()
    start_signal = pyqtSignal(bool)
    stop_signal = pyqtSignal(bool)
    update_plot_timer = QTimer()
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.update_plot_timer.setInterval(100)
        self.update_plot_timer.timeout.connect(self.emit_timer_out_signal)
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def emit_timer_out_signal(self):
        self.timer_out.emit()
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        self.update_plot_timer.stop()
```

in MainWindow() class the Qthread() and Worker() setup is like this

```
class MainWindow(Qw.QMainWindow):
    test_mode_signal = pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self):
# some other code
        self.start_test_button.clicked.connect(self.start_test_mode)
# some other code
        self.stop_test_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_test_mode)
# some other code
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.update_plot_timer.start)
        self.stop_test_button.clicked.connect(self.worker.stop)
        self.worker.timer_out.connect(self.update_plot)
# some other code
    def start_test_mode(self):
        self.streamData()
        self.audio_subplot.set_ylim([-1,1])
        self.audio_subplot.set_xlim([0,2000])
        self.start_test_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.stop_test_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.start_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.stop_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker_thread.start()
    def stop_test_mode(self):
        self.audio_inputstream.stop()
        self.audio_buffer.clear()
        self.start_test_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.stop_test_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.start_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.stop_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker_thread.quit()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.ani.event_source.stop()
```

update_plot() method, used blitting for performance

```
    def update_plot(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.realtime_update, blit=True, cache_frame_data=False, repeat=False)
    def realtime_update(self, _):
        self.audio_line.set_data(range(len(self.audio_buffer)),self.audio_buffer)
        return self.audio_line,
```

streamData() method

```
    def streamData(self):
        self.audio_inputstream = sd.InputStream(callback=self.callback,blocksize=1024,channels=1)
        self.audio_inputstream.start()
    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        self.audio_buffer.extend(indata.copy().flatten())
```

any ideas how can i stop the flashing/stuttering from happening? Any part of Qthread I miss or matplotlib FuncAnimation that causes this?

Comment: What is the point of `Worker`? It doesn't do anything, except emitting signals, so moving it to another thread seems quite pointless. Besides, the problem is exactly there: QTimers can only be started/stopped from the thread in which they exist, which is normally the one in which they have been created, and in your case it is the main one. From your code, there seems to be no need for threading, at least for the timer part. OTOH, the `sd.InputStream` is probably threaded, which makes writing to `audio_buffer` in `callback()` extremely unsafe, so *that* should probably use QThread instead.